# Symfony/FOSUserBundle: How do I display a comment form on an article only if the visitor is logged in?

Tags: php, authorization, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have 3 entities: User (part of FOSUserBundle), Comment, Article.

I'd like to display a comment form on the article only of the visitor is logged in. It was displaying for everybody just fine.

My code doesn't work and also seems like very bad practice. I get "Variable "form" does not exist." because I'm stopping the form from getting passed to the view. Is the necessary if I put an if in the view? I'd appreciate any suggestions on how I can accomplish this!

Thanks a bunch.

My comment.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}


{% block body %}
    {% form_theme form 'form/fields.html.twig' %}
    {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') -%}
        <div class="form-group">{{ form_start(form) }}</div>
        <div class="form-group">{{ form_row(form.comment.title) }}</div>
        <div class="form-group">{{ form_row(form.comment.rating) }}</div>
        <div class="form-group">{{ form_row(form.comment.comment) }}</div>
        <div class="form-group">{{ form_row(form.comment.user.firstName) }}</div>
        <div class="form-group">{{ form_row(form.comment.user.lastName) }}</div>
        <div class="form-group">{{ form_row(form.comment.user.email) }}</div>

        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Create" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    {% else %}
        <p>Please log in to post a comment!</p>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

My show.html.twig (for articles)

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body_id 'articlepage' %}
{% block body %}

<h1>Article: {{ article.name }}</h1>

<div class="well"><div class="media">
    <div class="media-left media-top">
        <img class="media-object" src="{{ article.thumbnail }}">
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">

        <h4 class="media-heading">{{ article.name }}</h4>
        <p>{{ article.description }}</p>
    </div>
</div></div>




<h2>Article Comments:</h2>

{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Comment:index', {'article_id': article.id})) }}

<h2>Submit a new comment:</h2>
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Article:comment', {'id': article.id})) }}

{% endblock %}
```

**commentAction within ArticleController.php (a controller that gets embedded in the show.html.twig)**

```
public function commentAction(Request $request, Article $article)
{
    $auth_checker = $this->get('security.userization_checker');
    $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
    $user = $token->getUser();
    $isRoleUser = $auth_checker->isGranted('ROLE_USER');

    if($isRoleUser){
        $comment = new Comment();
        //Build the comment form. 

        $commentForm = $this->createFormBuilder($comment)
            ->add('comment', CommentType::class, array("label" => FALSE))
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('article_comment', array('id' =>$article->getId())))
            ->getForm();

        $commentForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($commentForm->isSubmitted() && $commentForm->isValid()) {

            //Update existing user or create new
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $comment = $commentForm->getData()->getComment();
            $user = $this->getUser($comment->getUser());

            //Update the existing comment or get a new one
            $user = $this->getUser($comment->getUser());
            $comment = $this->getComment($user, $article, $comment);

            //Set the user and article for the comment.
            $comment->setUser($user);
            $comment->setArticle($article);

            $em->persist($comment);
            $em->flush($comment);

            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('article_show', array('id' => $article->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('article/comment.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $commentForm->createView(),
        ));
    } else {
        return $this->render('article/comment.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether user logged in or not in your Twig templates, you could use `app.user` variable:

```
{% if app.user %}
    {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Comment:index', {'article_id': article.id})) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Ok great! That's what I've done now and it works like a charm. I wasn't sure if it was enough to have an "if" in the view or if there was a more conventional way to do it. Thanks for your response!